# append column to LINQ query result for jquery datatables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, and EF 6 with LINQ
I have this function which returns the JSON Result for Jquery Datatables.

```
public ActionResult Index(jQueryDataTableParamModel param = null)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && param != null)
            {

                var allCategories = _db.Categories.ToList();
                IEnumerable<Category> categories;
                var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
                var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
                Func<Category,string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex==1? c.Name :
                    sortColumnIndex==2? c.SortOrder.ToString(): c.Status.ToString());

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
                {
                    if(sortDirection == "desc"){
                    categories = (from category in allCategories
                                  where category.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                  select category).OrderByDescending(orderingFunction).Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        categories = (from category in allCategories
                                      where category.Name.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                      select category).OrderBy(orderingFunction).Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sortDirection == "desc") { 
                    categories = (from category in allCategories
                                  select category).OrderByDescending(orderingFunction).Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
                    }
                    else{
                        categories = (from category in allCategories
                                      select category).OrderBy(orderingFunction).Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
                    }
                }
                return Json(new
                {
                    sEcho = param.sEcho,
                    iTotalRecords = categories.Count(),
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = categories.Count(),
                    aaData = (from category in categories
                              select new[] { category.CategoryID.ToString(), category.Name, category.SortOrder.ToString() }).ToArray()
                },
                                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

What i want is to append a column in json result which contains any string value such as html button or anchor tag etc.

Right now with Above code i am getting result like this..

```
{"sEcho":"3","iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3,"aaData":[["1","Computers","1"],["2","Laptops","4"],["3","Mobiles","3"]]}
```

but i want result with extra column in `aaData`.
example:

```
{"sEcho":"3","iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3,"aaData":[["1","Computers","1","<a href='somelink'>ActionLink</a>"],["2","Laptops","4","<a href='somelink'>ActionLink</a>"],["3","Mobiles","3","<a href='somelink'>ActionLink</a>"]]}
```

How can i achieve such a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 aaData = (from category in categories
                              select new[] { category.CategoryID.ToString(), category.Name, category.SortOrder.ToString() }).ToArray()
```

To This

```
 aaData = (from category in categories
                              select new[] { category.CategoryID.ToString(), category.Name, category.SortOrder.ToString(),"<a href='somelink'>ActionLink</a>" }).ToArray()
```